# R for skip to the next row if condition met and then another condition to check

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I know there are a lot of questions already posted on this but I am unable to apply the solution to my issue.

I have a dataset with many rows and columns. Below is a sample:

```
V7  V8  V9
0   1   0
-1  1   -1
-1  1   -1
-1  0   -1
-1  0   -1
-1  0   -1
-1  0   -1
-1  1   -1
0   1   -1
0   1   -1
-1  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   -1  0
0   -1  -1
0   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   0
```

This data is saved in a matrix `trboot3`
What I want to do is create a loop whereby two conditions are checked and data is altered.

1. If there is a zero, skip to the next row.
2. If there is same number one below another in a row, keep the first number and change the rest to zero.

Here is my code for the above loop:

```
trboot4<-trboot3
valboot<-length(trboot3[,1])
for (k in 1:length(trboot3[1,])){
  for (i in 2:valboot-1){
    if (trboot3[k,i]==0) {i<-i+1}
    else{
      if(trboot3[k,i] == trboot3[k,i+1]){
        for (j in i+1:valboot){ if(trboot3[k,j] == trboot3[k,i]){trboot4[k,j]<-0}else{break}
          if(j==valboot){break}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to save the new matrix in `trboot4`

basically the above sample should become:

```
V7  V8  V9
0   1   0
-1  0   -1
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
-1  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   -1  0
0   0   -1
0   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   0
```

Comment: Does the current loop work ? If it works, is it too slow ?

Comment: Hi @digEmAll there is no error except for `subscript out of bounds` for the current loop. but my output for trboot4 is the same as for trboot3. And no it is not slow at least for me.

Comment: I've provided a solution not using loop, BTW to get the number of columns and rows of a matrix you can use nrow and ncol functions, you don't need to do : `length(m[,1])` etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`rle`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) and [`apply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) functions :

```
# re-create your matrix
trboot3 <- structure(c(0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,0, 1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
-1,0,0,0),.Dim = c(20L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V7", "V8", "V9")))

keepFirstValueIfRepeated <- function(v){
  RLE <- rle(v)
  firstIndex <- (cumsum(RLE$lengths)- RLE$lengths + 1)
  v2 <- rep.int(0,length(v))
  v2[firstIndex] <- RLE$values
  return(v2)
}

trboot4 <- apply(trboot3,2,FUN=keepFirstValueIfRepeated)
```

Result :

```
 > trboot4
      V7 V8 V9
 [1,]  0  1  0
 [2,] -1  0 -1
 [3,]  0  0  0
 [4,]  0  0  0
 [5,]  0  0  0
 [6,]  0  0  0
 [7,]  0  0  0
 [8,]  0  1  0
 [9,]  0  0  0
[10,]  0  0  0
[11,] -1  0  0
[12,]  0  0  0
[13,]  0  0  0
[14,]  0  0  0
[15,]  0  0  0
[16,]  0 -1  0
[17,]  0  0 -1
[18,]  0  0  0
[19,]  0  1  0
[20,]  0  0  0
```

**Explanation :**

Let's start from the first custom function `keepFirstValueIfRepeated` which gets a vector `v` and keeps only the first value in a sequence of consecutive equal values, forcing the others to zero.
How is it implemented ?

We use [`rle`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) function which is very useful to analyze sub-sequence of consecutive equal values, in fact it returns a list with the lengths of the sub-sequences and the repeated values of each sub-sequence.
The idea is to keep only the first element of a sub-sequence of repeated values; so, first of all, we compute `firstIndex` containing all the indexes of the first element of a sub-sequence, then we create a vector `v2` of the same length of `v` but with all zeros, and finally we put the first values of the sub-sequences inside of `v2`.

After this, we need to "apply" this function (`keepFirstValueIfRepeated`) to each column of `trboot3`, and this is exactly what `apply(matrix,2,FUN)` does

Comment: hi @digEmAll can i trouble you to explain how the rle function works please in this context? thank you

Comment: Yep, I'm doing it ;)

Comment: thank you because I have to code further on it and will probably end up using similar code since loop is not working

Comment: @Ash:I've simplified the code and wrote an explanation... I hope it's clear enough...

Comment: thank you so much.. understood the code so easily with the explanation.

Comment: how do i modify RLE such that the sum of the repeated values does not exceed 2 and if it does, the second repeated value is set to zero?

Comment: Mmh... I didn't fully get your question... can you provide a small example ?

Comment: suppose i have a sample: 1,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0. So once i eliminate all zeros, every pair must have one positive 1 and one negative 1. in the above, we get (1,-1),(-1,1),(1,1). the last pair has two positive 1s. I want to change the last 1 to 0

Comment: @Ash: I don't understand how this relates to the question in this post... maybe you should open a new question...

Comment: I have posted a new question here-> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959858/r-apply-function-with-if-statements-to-every-elements-in-list)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
library(Hmisc)
trboot4 = apply(trboot3, 2, function(c) c * (c!=Lag(c)))
trboot4[1,] = trboot3[1,]
```

Comment: hello! could you please explain how the Lag() function works? thank you